# How to update a container within a system started by docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a whole system started with docker compose.

It is made of a few containers and also contains info regarding the connectivity.

For example:

```
librarian:
    image: autobot-librarian
    ports:
       - 4000:80
    depends_on:
       - mongodb
    links:
       - mongodb
```

In this case, this container can access mongodb.

I would like to be able to update the image of a single container and replace it on the fly, without shutting down the whole system.

I can stop a container, and restart it with a new image, but the connectivity established by docker-compose is not present anymore.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: did you try execute `docker-compose` for only one service? something like `docker-compose pull librarian && docker-compose up -d librarian`. This allow you only restart one service, the only problem with this approach is going to restart any other service that depends on librarian

Comment: I did not know this was possible! I thought docker-compose was an all or nothing solution! restarting dependent services is fine. Thanks for the info, you can post it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `docker-compose` to manage one or more service at time. In this case, if you want to update one image you have to do:

```
docker-compose pull librarian
```

After that, if you want update the container:

```
docker-compose up -d librarian
```

This only restart one service and all the services that depend on it (defined in the docker-compose as `depends_on`).